# Cleaning up nodes in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, svg

I have the following SVG:

[image]

I am using Inkscape to create and edit this SVG. I wanted to have my Mask layer as the background and put all the other stuff on top of it. So to do that I duplicated all the layers and combined them into one, which filled everything and gave me the background I needed as you can see.

[image]

However, as you can also see, there's a ton of nodes inside this layer and I wanted to get rid of them. I tried using combine or union. After using union I ended up with fewer nodes, but ideally, I'd like nodes just on the outlines. Can someone help me get rid of all the nodes inside the layer?

Thanks

Comment: Hmm . . . looks like some of the squares may not be physically/exactly touching. Don't use Combine however, Union should be the correct operation.  Can you share the SVG file on SVGshare, and I can take a look.

Comment: Redrawing the outline while using a grid would take just a minute or so. Or you could make a bitmap copy and trace that, that's even faster.

Comment: Oh, or, the trick solution could work, too. Set the precision of the SVG file saving in Inkscape's preferences to a low value, and then use union again.